# Can i enter my component as a provider in other component in angular 6?

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ip-ill',
  templateUrl: './ip-ill.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ip-ill.component.css'],
  providers: [FormComponent]
})
```

Can i add FormComponent as provider in my Other component and access variable values from FormComponent?

Comment: what is the reason for making your component as provider ?

Comment: No need to add it in provider you are able to inject any parent component, but please do take care how you wanna get the instance of that component with special injector decorators such @Optional() or @SkipSelf()